# Make div expand outside of scrolling parent

Tags: html, css, hover, position, css-position

I have a table with some cloumns that can be hovered over to show some items inside a div. This table is inside a container with max height and overflow: auto. The problem is that when I hover over a column, I want the items to expand outside the parent div aswell as position itself to the column that is hovered.

```
    <div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropbtn">Hover here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <p>Item 1</p>
              <p>Item 2</p>
              <p>Item 3</p>
              <p>Item 4</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
         </tr>
...
```

css:

```
.dropdown {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.table-container {
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

I have played around with the position property of the divs, but it seems I can only choose from either:

1. make the items expand outside parent, but the position is wrong
   when the table is scrolled
2. make the items position itself to the column, but the items does not expand outside of parent.

Here is a fiddle of my problem: (try to scroll down and hover an item)
https://jsfiddle.net/wuj9fd5c/3/

***Edit:***
Updated fiddle to explain both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some js code to set top and left for dropdown-content.

First I had to set the position for the parent to static:

```
.dropdown {
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.dropbtn', function () {
    var $posTop = $(this).position().top;
    var $posLeft = $(this).position().left + 20;
    $(this).parent().children(".dropdown-content").css({ top: $posTop, left: $posLeft });
});
```